# How is client-side authorization with VueRouter safe?

Tags: vue.js, security, vue-router

EDIT: In a single-page-app, ALL of the static content is loaded in the SPA, so if there is anything remotely sensitive in the static content, it can be viewed from within the browser. The only solution is to not use SPAs and render authorized pages from the server side, and if those pages require modelview AJAX JS controllers, don't exponse anything sensitive in the controller code, as that will be served static too.

I've studied the code for VueRouter and read several other examples that use guards and prechecks to perform authentication (either by a cookie or session data token) to block certain routes unless the user has permission.

I don't understand how this is safe? The VueRouter example blocks the dashboard page, but I can literally view the so-called "blocked" page in the browser debug console, and then edit the JavaScript in the source panel to bypass the authorization by deleting the check in the requireAuth function and replace with 'next()'.

I'm clearly missing something, but if the content and javascript can be viwed/edited in browser, how is this a valid method of authorizing parts of your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Securing your app should be done in backend since you have full control of that machine. VueRouter, as you clearly said, is typically used for showing/hiding UI elements depending on *authentication* and *authorization*. You always must assume that anyone could read and modify your frontend in their local machines.

To be clear, It doesn't matter whether you're using Vue, React or any other frontend framework, security **must** be applied in the backend.

Comment: So I'm right in that server side rendering is a requirement for authorization? E.g., after authenticating on the backend and obtaining a token, it is ultimately up to the server to detremine which pages to render (whether PHP or Node...). So it doesn't make sense to ever have pages requiring authorization in the static/public area (instead they should be rendered by a GET endpoint after authorizing, right?)

Comment: I don't quite know the architecture of your app, but I can tell you that we *typically* authorize or not each HTTP endpoint depending on if the user is logged and their role is allowed for the action that he/she claims.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've always done, but got thrown for a loop with dozens of Vue toturials explaining how to authorize client-side. The server has to verify each endpoint, you can't just send the entire SPA and then decide what to show client side --- you still have to fetch the data to populate the SPA's reactive fields, but you're still exposing SOME of the content in the SPA because it is static. Thanks!